# How do I install a fire extinguisher on the side of a cabinet?

Tags: installation, cabinets, fire-extinguisher

I want to hang my fire extinguisher on the cabinet next to my sink. Below are pictures of the fire extinguisher bracket and the location where I want to put it. Should I use a bolt with a nut - or some sort of screw?

[image: Mounting bracket]

[image: Side of cabinet]

[image: Fire extinguisher]

Comment: You could improve this post by making the pictures in to thumbnails that link to the full-sized image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably too heavy for wood screws into chipboard cabinets.
If the screws don't work then a couple of bolts with penny washers.

The extinguisher looks a bit battered, you should check the trigger mechanism looks ok. BUT don't try and squirt it a little bit - the cooling gas can make ice form in the valve and stop it turning off

Comment: The trigger mechanism appears to be OK. My wife's cousin is moving, so he gave me a bunch of stuff I had been needing. The outer of the extinguisher looks beat up, but the trigger mechanism is good. The gauge shows full charge. It feels heavy so I believe that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the holes on the mounting bracket are shaped for a bugle head, which AFAIK limits you to using a screw.  (Well, you could use a bolt, but the head would push the extinguisher out so that it's not parallel to the cabinet face which would look untidy, IMO.)

If your cabinets are 3/4" plywood, the screws probably all you need.  If they're made from particleboard, you should add some reinforcement in the form of extra wood to hold onto: glue a piece of plywood to the inside of the cabinet and screw into that.  Most cabinets that I've seen have a lip around the front edges, so if you use a piece that doesn't protrude past that lip and fills the full depth of the cabinet and the height between the shelves, it'll be less noticeable.

Comment: They are particleboard. Good idea about the plywood.

Comment: You can get a screw head that is threaded for a nut.

Comment: @bmitch: I couldn't find any in a search at Lowe's or HD's websites.  But using one would still leave you with a nut/washer/bolt on the inside of the cabinet which I for one would find ugly.

Comment: @Niall: The term to search for is "machine screw".  If you cut it to the right size, you can use a "cap nut" instead of a normal nut, which would look a bit better, but I'm pretty sure it would be a pain to install since they limit the depth of the bolt.  You might be able to find a plastic cap, similar to what you have on the toilet base, if you look hard enough.